# C++ How to hold lots of arrays dynamically?

Tags: c++, arrays, sdl, sdl-2, minimax

Okay so basically I am building a simple checkers game using C++ SDL2 library

Currently I am holding the game board state data in a 8x8 2d array which is all the possible board spaces on a checkerboard.
The value inside the array is either: 0 for empty space, 1 for red checker, 2 for blue checker.

I have basically the entire game done using this board as the logic and I am now going to be implementing the minimax algorithm to add computer AI as the opponent. So what I need to do is get all the possible board states and use that in the algorithm. Right now I am trying to find the right way to approach storing a bunch of arrays (board states) in a dynamic way since I will not know exactly every time how many states there will be. Is there any easy way to use a main array to hold all the board states (2d Arrays)? It needs to be dynamic, and  arrays can only be static right?

Comment: Make a class that's a wrapper around `std::array<checkerType, 8 * 8>` and provide 2D indexing. Then you can create an `std::vector` of those. Probably the simples and optimal in terms of efficiency choice, if you happen to really have a lot of them.

Comment: You can create dynamic arrays by just allocating memory. int* array = new int[x]; You could embed this in some class that makes sure to clean them up when unused by adding a delete[] array; in the destructor.

Comment: @DutchJelly advising someone to use `new` in modern C++ is most of the time a bad idea. As for the "*You could embed this in some class that makes sure to clean them up when unused by adding a delete[] array; in the destructor.*" - that's exactly what smart pointers do.

Comment: @Fureeish struct A { int board[8][8];};                                                                                    
std::vector<A> v; ??

Comment: @Imurdock12 see my answer.

Comment: Given that each board space can be represented by three possible values, you can optimise the storage for the board (e.g. represent each space by two bits, times 64 spaces, gives 128 bits, which can be represented using exactly 16 `unsigned char` - which are guaranteed to be 8 bits or more).  Create a type to handle that.   Then use a `std::vector` of that type, and emulate 2D indexing.   Yes, there is a runtime cost of indexing and extracting/setting board spaces, but that overhead will be dwarfed by the working of most AI algorithms.

Comment: @Fureeish Well I was just trying to give some more options of allocating dynamic arrays and to show how it works memory-management-wise.

Comment: For storing the board cell values you could also use pointers to booleans. That way you can have the three values ``NULL``, ``*true``, ``*false``. This allocating of the memory off the stack could slow your application down tho, but I think it could be helpful if you run into memory issues.

Comment: @DutchJelly First of all, **never** advise someone to use `NULL` post `C++11`. Second of all, why use pointers here at all? For optional values, simply use `std::optional`. There is absolutely no reason to use pointers to store the values of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a wrapper class around `std::array<checker_type, 8 * 8>` (since emulating 2D array using a 1D arrays usually proves to be faster due to caching). This way you can easily create and copy such boards.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace game {
    enum class checker_type {
        empty, red, blue
    };

    struct board {
        std::array<checker_type, 8 * 8> data{};

        struct proxy_row {
            std::array<checker_type, 8 * 8>& data_ref;
            const std::size_t row;

            proxy_row(std::array<checker_type, 64>& data_ref, const size_t row) noexcept
                    : data_ref(data_ref), row(row) { }

            checker_type& operator [] (const std::size_t col) const noexcept {
                return data_ref[8 * row + col];
            }
        };

        struct const_proxy_row {
            const std::array<checker_type, 8 * 8>& data_ref;
            const std::size_t row;

            const_proxy_row(const std::array<checker_type, 64>& data_ref, const size_t row) noexcept
            : data_ref(data_ref), row(row) { }

            const checker_type& operator [] (const std::size_t col) const noexcept {
                return data_ref[8 * row + col];
            }
        };

        proxy_row operator [] (const std::size_t row) noexcept {
            return proxy_row(data, row);
        };

        const_proxy_row operator [] (const std::size_t row) const noexcept {
            return const_proxy_row(data, row);
        }
    };
}

void print_board(const game::board& board) noexcept {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j) {
            std::cout << static_cast<int>(board[i][j]) << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

As for creating multiple boards to run minmax algorithm, you can use an `std::vector` - a class template which provides a dynamic array functionality with lots of utilities:

```
int main() {
    game::board board{};

    board[0][0] = game::checker_type::blue;
    board[1][1] = game::checker_type::blue;
    board[2][2] = game::checker_type::red;

    print_board(board);

    std::vector<game::board> boards{};

    const auto size = 1000;
    boards.reserve(size); // reserve memory for *size* boards
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        boards.emplace_back(); // creating *size* boards to run minmax algorithm
    }
}
```

To elaborate a little bit on your thought process:

> Right now I am trying to find the right way to approach storing a bunch of arrays (board states) in a dynamic way since I will not know exactly every time how many states there will be.

You are correct that you want a dynamic way of storing some data if you do not know beforehand how much memory that data will require. `std::vector` is an excellent tool to handle that.

> [Array] needs to be dynamic, and arrays can only be static right?

Wrong. First of all, *static* is **not** the opposite of *dynamic*. You can have a dynamic, static array (for example `static int* arr = new int[10];`).

Comment: Hey @Fureeish bear with me here...I assume you are doing some special stuff here to reduce the memory load with your board. Why exactly is the downside to the following simple solution?   Create a simple struct: struct board { int grid[8][8] };  For example create two test boards using: board test1; test1.grid[0][0] = 1; board test2; test2.grid[0][0] = 2;  create and populate vector: vector<test> boards; boards.push_back(test1) boards.push_back(test2).. I know I didn't populate all the grid spots but I am able to successfully loop through vector and get the data so what is wrong with approach?

Comment: @lmurdock12 there is nothing technically "*wrong*" with your approach. However, one should not use C-style arrays. `std::array<T, N>` is preferred. Actually thinking about this now I came to a conclusion that `std::array<std::array, 8>, 8>` will be more concise and easier to work with. The proxy objects I used are usually used with dynamic multidimensional arrays, where we do not need one in `board`. Good that you questioned my approach. I simply advise not to use `T[N]`, a C-style array. Use `std::array<T, N>`. Leaving the answer and the comments as they are for educational purposes.

Comment: okay cool thanks for your help, I think at first the answer seemed oddly complicated to me after coming from a language like python...going to do more research on the differences now